# Is it acceptable to extend results from an arXiv paper that has not appeared in a journal?

Tags: publications, etiquette, arxiv

In general, building on unpublished work of another author, which he may have told you in  confidence, or you may encountered as a reviewer or by word of mouth or other informal means, is not an acceptable practice. Does the same apply if the author has uploaded his work on arXiv?

Here's a specific scenario: Suppose I submit a paper for review to a journal. The paper has results that could possibly be extended, however, the idea for extension is either not obvious or is not compatible with the theme of the paper, so I may plan to keep it for a  later paper. If I put the paper on arXiv would it be considered ok if someone else extends my results? This would ruin the theme of the other paper I wanted to write with the extension.

If this happened to me it would make me uncomfortable, as if my confidence has been breached. I don't know if this feeling is justified. This feeling stems from my view of arXiv. My personal theory is that arXiv is an informal medium, unlike journals and conferences, and in that sense it is no different from other channels of informal communication. It allows for structured and faster dissemination of work (thus inform the ongoing work of others), in addition to establishing priority of results, but that does not grant it a formal status. I think an author should exercise restraint in extending results from arXiv, and apply the same standards that he would if he were to encounter the work through classical informal channels.

Of course, this is just my theory. I would like to hear what others have to say about this issue.

Comment: I do not understand the question at all. What you learn as a reviewer is very confidential information. What people have posted on well-known public web sites is very public information. To me these seem to be the opposite extremes, not similar situations. One of the main benefits in posting to Arxiv is that others can start building on your work. In the best case, you have already lots of citations even before your paper is formally published. This is great, from everyone's perspective.

Comment: its a public archive. non prior-publication peer reviewed. (but post publication peer-reviewed). to call papers there "unpublished" does not make total sense. its electronic publishing. it would be a courtesy to contact the authors of paper one wants to extend. in rare/best cases it might lead to a new coauthored paper. but should not be expected.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about academia.SE. Could the mods help me "move" the question there? Also, if worth the while, perhaps the words "considered ok" in the title can be changed to merely "ok". This way people can give their opinion on it, rather than describe what they perceive as the general opinion.

Comment: I am confused by your addition in revision 5.  Do you want to argue that your logic is correct and other people should follow it?  If so, you are on a wrong website; this is a place for questions and answers, not a place to discuss what we should do.  Your logic is reasonable, but it is not the only reasonable logic.  In the current community of theoretical computer science, I do not think that people employ that logic.  I thought that your question was “Do other people act according to this view?”, so I answered no.  If you want to convert other people, please do it somewhere else.

Comment: No I don't mean to convert anyone or initiate a discussion. I only meant to clarify my theory. Furthermore, the topic has been changed to "is it considered ok to" to "is it wrong to", so therefore answers are now solicited about whether people think it is right or wrong, not merely what people perceive other people to consider ok. So I thought I should expand on why I felt it was wrong. I don't plan to keep editing the above in response to all responses I receive and as such don't plan to indulge in an argument. I have also removed any references to responses in the new edit.

Comment: "Is this _considered_ right or wrong" is asking for an objective evaluation of publication culture.  "Is this _actually_ right or wrong?" is asking for personal opinion.  The former question is in scope for this site; the latter question is not.  I've removed the argumentative edit.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela: it is not always great.  I know several people who do not put their work on arxiv because of the following (real) case: author A puts a big result in the arxiv and submits to a very good journal; the journal takes almost a year to referee it, and ends up rejecting by reason of standards (i.e. there's nothing wrong with the paper, it is just not good enough for our super journal). But during that year B and C read the arxiv paper, find a generalization,  and get it published (acknowledging A's preprint). So, after a year, author A finds himself with his best work unpublishable.

Answer (score 59):

I understand your logic, but I do not think that many people treat papers on arXiv in that way.  Papers on arXiv are public unlike the papers you reviewed or the work you just heard by personal communication.  As such, extending the results in a paper on arXiv is a perfectly acceptable practice as long as the second paper cites the paper on arXiv properly.

Comment: Just to make sure, I had posted this answer when the question was posted on cstheory.stackexchange.com, and therefore it is my implicit assumption that the question is about a paper in theoretical computer science.  Because different fields have different research practices including the roles of journals and preprints, this answer may not apply to other fields which also use arXiv.org.

Comment: I believe building on ArXiv preprints is also standard practice in mathematics and physics, which are much heavier users of ArXiv than theoretical computer science.

Comment: @Jeffe Do you think theoretical CS uses the arXiv less because they rely so heavily on conferences (rather than journals), and thus typically disseminate their results more rapidly than math and physics?

Comment: No, I think theoretical computer science uses the ArXiv less because computer scientists are generally Luddites.  No, I am not joking.

Comment: One of the main points of preprint archives like arXiv is to get papers available ASAP, so others can build on your results sooner thus speeding up science.

Answer (score 29):

I feel like publishing something on arXiv is an act of "publishing" nonetheless.

It has the advantages of publishing. These include: getting your work out there (with more visibility than if simply posting it on your webpage , which requires people be looking for your articles), getting people interested in it, and perhaps even getting citations before the paper has gone through the long and grueling process of being validated by a journal. It also had the advantage of showing that this is your result, thus preventing anybody from "preempting" you.

But then it also has the "disadvantage" that someone may run with your idea, and extend it, possibly even obtaining a result that is more significant than your own.

This does not mean publishing things on arXiv should be seen as a risk. It means that publishing on arXiv, like anywhere else, should be a well-thought decision. Note that with all the turmoil surrounding official journals, and common practices, it seems we are slowly evolving towards archives such as arXiv getting increasing legitimacy.

So to answer your question: an article on arXiv is not "unpublished" at all (unlike papers you get to read as a referee, or which a colleague has shared with you in confidence---those are other issues altogether), so yes, there is generally nothing wrong with extending results.

Answer (score 22):

As the other replies say, putting your paper on a public archive is a way of making it public, and so other researchers may build on the results.

One thing to do when you want to make your work public, but you're also working on extensions that will take more time to establish, is to explicitly write in the paper you publish that you have an ongoing work on those extensions.
This at least lets people know what the situation is. You can't control what people are going to do with this information, but I think that reasonable people would not immediately start working on the same extensions, and, if at some point they do want to work on these extensions, they are likely to contact you to check what's going on.

Of course, this "ongoing work" statement should be used only when it's appropriate and there's really an ongoing work that is likely to be completed within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: This is a good idea but it is made harder today with the annoying practice in some fields of claiming "future work" directions, without indication of whether the authors actually intend to pursue them or not.

Answer (score 20):

In mathematics, it is very common to build on papers that are on arXiv.  Indeed, this is more or less the whole point of arXiv: to disseminate work faster than the journal publication cycle, so that the community can immediately begin to make use of it, which includes extending it.  If you wait until the paper is published, you will be well behind the curve.

I don't think your reservations about building on "unpublished" work are applicable here.  At least in mathematics, preprints are generally posted on arXiv at the same time as they are *submitted* for publication; they are thus already in the "final" form intended by the authors.  Of course it may be that further revisions take place before publication (perhaps as a result of the peer review process), but the arXiv version is usually perfectly suitable as a foundation for future work.

However, a few extra caveats are in order:

- Since a paper from arXiv has not passed peer review yet, you should probably be even more diligent than usual about checking its results before using them.  If you find errors or unclear points, it would behoove you to alert the authors, since they may be able to be corrected before publication.
- Conversely, you should also keep an eye out for updates to the preprint which may contain important corrections.
- You may certainly cite the arXiv preprint in your own paper.  However, you should check for a published version before final acceptance of your own (and again when correcting the proofs), and update the citation if necessary.

Answer (score 12):

> There is however one more important distinction between arXiv and journals/conferences. Whatever is published in journals/conferences is final and can no more be revised. It is as if the author has said all that he has to say on the topic and it is now fair game for others to say what they want.

Whether this is a meaningful distinction depends on the circumstances: it's common to write a series of papers on a given topic, in which case no single paper contains all the author has to say on the topic.

The other answers have clearly explained how the communities that use the arXiv view this matter.  However, I'd go a step further: a system where people could stake out credit for unpublished work while preventing other people from building on it would be bad for science.  Currently, this is the trade-off researchers face.  You can keep your ideas private for as long as you want, to give you time to exploit them fully.  However, you run the risk that someone else may independently discover them.  In that case, the best you can hope for is to share the credit if you promptly make your work public (and make a convincing case that it was independent).  On the other hand, if you circulate a paper publicly, then you no longer need to worry about credit, but anyone can use your ideas.  This is very reasonable: credit is not awarded for being smart or accomplished, but rather for contributing to the community, and that contribution is the ideas.  Being able to use and build on these ideas is why they are so valuable, and this is the justification for awarding credit.

The alternative to this trade-off would be to allow researchers to claim credit while temporarily reserving the exclusive right to do follow-up work.  In that case, the optimal strategy would be clear: make a public announcement as soon as you cross the neecessary threshold, but then delay finalizing the work for as long as possible.  This would be very disruptive for the research community.

In practice, things are slightly less black and white than I've described them above.  It can be considered rude to compete too strenuously without a very good reason. If you come up with a minor idea building on someone else's work in progress, it's common to donate it to them rather than competing, and a major idea may lead to a collaboration.  However, this is a matter of politeness rather than ethics.

Answer (score 6):

There is a risk in releasing your results early (since others may build on your work before you do it), but there is also a risk in *not* doing it (since an article doing the exact same thing may appear before you make your preprint public).

There are also other advantages in publishing early (and, more in general, making your work known in conferences before it is fully peer-reviewed):

- instead of "stealing your ideas", people may contact you and propose a collaboration.
- if people know your work, they can cite you.

That is why I suggest releasing early, at least in my field (numerical linear algebra --- which, I realize, is a quite friendly and relaxed field, so your mileage may vary).

Answer (score 5):

I upvoted all the earlier answers... and want to reiterate certain points. First, arXiv (and stable personally-maintained web-sites, e.g., at universities) should count as "publication" in the sense of making the information *available*, which is the ideal point of research.

Yes, there is some conflict with "the other" point, namely, staking a claim, getting credit, getting a job, getting tenure. But, as others have pointed out, it would have a bad effect if one could "stake a claim" without divulging details, thereby stifling others' work (if they needed to hope to get some "credit" also).

(There has always been an analogous hazard for beginners, all the worse pre-internet, that senior people can be "rumored" to be "working on something", circulated in mimeo to friends, etc. Mercifully, this is now diminished, I think, exactly because there's no excuse for limiting circulation.)

As Anon Math and others said, of *course* it is more civil to offer collaboration rather than to compete directly, etc., and this is vastly more consistent with our ideal of advancing knowledge (rather than mere *self*-advancement, as necessary as some of the latter may be).

In summary, then, yes, a relative novice risks having their ideas taken up by more experienced people. Yes, in particular, some people are able to rationalize that non-refereed papers need not be cited at all! This is, of course, barbaric. :)

Answer (score 3):

A few points to add -

Why publish things on arxiv?  So that others know your results.  This is only relevant if you can get others to start using your results.  It'll increase your citation count and speed up progress.  You run the risk of getting people who publish things you want to do in the future.

What to do about the risk?  You can explicitly state you plan on doing X.  If I'm already doing X, that might light a fire and get me to quickly finish.  Or I might try to collaborate with you.  If I'm not already doing X, would it be wise for me to compete with you?  I don't know how far along you are, but you're almost surely ahead of me - would I really put in the effort to try to catch up with such a high risk of being scooped?  No.

So if you tell people you plan to do an extension the real risk you run is that someone else who is already doing it might speed up their work, not that someone will come along and start up quickly.